# How to ignore everything except a folder and all it's subfolders / contents in git

Tags: git, gitignore

In my `.gitignore` I have:

```
*
!file.txt
!folder1
!folder1/
!folder1/*
```

This almost does what I want except whenever I add something beyond one folder past `folder/` it does not get committed. For instance `folder1/test/folder2/test.txt` will not be committed.  Is there any way to fix this without adding endless `*` to my `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I kept playing with this, and here is a shorter version

```
/*          # ignore everything in root
!/folder1   # except folder1
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Give this a shot

```
*
!folder1
!folder1/**
```

From [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/gitignore):

> Two consecutive asterisks ("**") in patterns matched against full
>   pathname may have special meaning:
>
> ...
>
> - A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the
>     location of the .gitignore file,
>            with infinite depth.
>
> ...